# mysql_escape_string vulnerabilities

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I was explaining parametrization and its advantages to my friend recently, and he asked how it was any better than `mysqli_escape_string` in terms of security. Specifically, can you think of any examples of SQL injection that would succeed despite the input strings being escaped (using mysqli_escape_string)?

UPDATE:

I apologise for not being clear enough in my original question. The general question being asked here is, is SQL injection possible despite escaping input strings?

Comment: from the manual: > This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this
> feature is highly discouraged. Do not put effort in deprecated code. Use parameter binding, no worries about SQL injection.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the 
community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See
 the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared
 statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://in3.php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you.
 If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO).
 Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: I know this already, I am not advocating the use of the mysql extension. I am simply asking you to illustrate **how** it is vulnerable.

Comment: This is because it was replaced with `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, not because you should not escape strings anymore.

Comment: @Asad: You never know, as it is a internal function of PHP. You would have to look in the source code to figure it out

Comment: Maybe you should replace `mysql_escape_string()` with `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to get better answers.

Comment: Check out this slideshow of [**SQL myths and fallacies**](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies). It should answer any SQL injection questions you have.

Comment: @martinstoeckli: That change also makes a difference for the answers :)

Comment: @Jon how does it make a difference for the answers? If I were to ask a hypothetical question about B language, I would prefer not to recieve answers that tell me to use C++ instead.

Comment: @Jon - Agreed, but i think the question was about "escaping strings" versus "parametrized queries" from the start. It was just a inattention of Asad and the "unuseful" answers didn't stop otherwise.

Comment: Gaah, @Jon, I was all bubbly and happily writing my answer, and not only you beat me to the punch, my answer *does not even apply anymore*. `*cries*`

Comment: @Iserni Jon - I'm sorry to have ruined your answers, but maybe you know an answer to the new question as well?

Comment: @martinstoeckli: I have updated the answer to cover the current question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Updated answer

The question was edited (after my answer was posted) to specifically target `mysqli_escape_string`, which is an alias of `mysql_real_escape_string` and therefore takes the connection encoding into account. This makes the original answer non-applicable anymore, but I 've left it for completeness.

The new answer, in short: **`mysqli_escape_string` is as good security-wise as parameterized queries, provided you don't shoot yourself in the foot**.

Specifically, what you must not do is highlighted in the giant warning on the PHP [doc page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php):

> The character set must be set either at the server level, or with the
>   API function `mysqli_set_charset()` for it to affect
>   `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

If you don't heed this warning (i.e. if you change the character set with a direct `SET NAMES` query) *and* you change the character set from a single-byte encoding to a "convenient" (from the attacker's perspective) multibyte encoding, you will have in effect emulated what the dumb `mysql_escape_string` does: attempt to escape characters without knowing which encoding the input is in.

This situation leaves you potentially vulnerable to SQL injection as described by the original answer below.

**Important note:** I remember reading somewhere that recent MySql versions have plugged this hole on their end (in the client libraries?), which means that you *might* be perfectly safe even if using `SET NAMES` to switch to a vulnerable multibyte encoding. But please don't take my word for it.

#### Original answer

In contrast to `mysql_real_escape_string`, the bare `mysql_escape_string` does not take into account the [connection encoding](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-connection.html). This means that it assumes the input is in a single-byte encoding, when in fact it can legitimately be in a multibyte encoding.

Some multibyte encodings have byte sequences that correspond to a single character where one of the bytes is the ASCII value of the single quote (`0x27`); if fed such a string, `mysql_escape_string` will happily "escape the quote", which means substituting `0x27` with `0x5c` `0x27`. Depending on the encoding rules, this could result in mutating the multibyte character into another that includes the `0x5c` *and leaving the "remaining" `0x27` as a stand-alone single quote in the input*. Voilà, you have injected an unescaped quote into the SQL.

For more details see [this blog post](http://ilia.ws/archives/103-mysql_real_escape_string-versus-Prepared-Statements.html).

Comment: +1 for being pretty much the only on topic answerer. Must have been downvoted because you didn't include the words **HIGHLY DISCOURAGED** in bold capitals in your answer

Comment: @Asad: You specifically did not ask for something like that, so I guess it's your fault :)

Comment: I specifically asked for examples of how SQL injection could occur when using mysql_escape_string. This is supported by the fact that my question asks `Specifically, can you think of any examples of SQL injection that would succeed despite the input strings being escaped`

Answer (score 4):

### The bad answer:

> Specifically, can you think of any examples of SQL injection that
>   would succeed despite the input strings being escaped (using
>   mysql_escape_string)?

Not reliably. You are referring to `mysql_escape_string()`, which does not take into account the connection encoding (while `mysql_real_escape_string()` does).

So maybe a carefully crafted string, with a carefully crafted incomplete UTF8 codepoint in front, *might* result in, say, a quote sign being escaped by `mysql_escape_string()` *but the escape itself being ignored by MySQL* since it will "see" it as an UTF8 character.

E.g.:

```
0xC2' OR 1=1 ;--
```

would be escaped by `mysql_escape_string()` as

```
0xC2\' OR 1=1 ;--
```

which would be assembled to

```
WHERE password='0xC2\' OR 1=1 ;--';
```

and seen by MySQL (if the proper connection encoding was in effect) as, say,

```
WHERE password='€' OR 1=1 ;[--';]    <-- the bracketed part is considered a comment and ignored
```

which would be a classic SQL injection.

But this plays on the fact that you specified, maybe through distraction, a **doubly deprecated function**. If you really were referring to `mysql_real_escape_string()`, then it would not work.

Also, this assumes that neither the server, nor the application layer (e.g. PHP) employs any kind of charset validation when populating the input. If they did, the invalid UTF8 would be deleted on arrival, and never even be seen by `mysql_escape_string`, which would then of course be enough.

### The real answer:

Do not use `mysql_escape_string` (or `mysql_whatever`) at all. They've been deprecated and your code might stop working. Use PDO functions instead.

Comment: nope, it would be assembled to `WHERE password='0xC2\' OR 1=1 ;--\'';`